# how much time does a scroll event last?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I meet a issue caused by scroll event, this problem can be reproduce as follows:

1. set focus to an element which is not seen in browser windows by default (need to scroll to see it).
2. then attach a listener to catch the scroll event.

what I confused is that when I set focus on the not seen element, it will trigger a scroll event, how can listener catch the scroll event for it attached later? I think maybe the scroll event will last for a while, but how long? can anyone can give me a suggestion?

here is a simple code to reproduce it:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var onchange = function(){
       var ip1 = document.getElementById("target");
       var ip2 = document.getElementById("source");
       var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
       ip2.focus();
       document.onscroll = function(e){
          console.log("scroll");
       };
   }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onchange()">
<input id="target"></input>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="parent">
 <input id="source">
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly the problem is that you are trying to solve here – and while a scroll event doesn’t actually “last” any longer than any other event, it can get triggered quite often during the process of scrolling a website, and than can have performance implications if you are trying to do something based on that event. A more in-depth explanation and a possible workaround using timers you can find here: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for this is that JavaScript event handlers do not immediately fire. Thus, when you call `focus()`, it doesn't immediately focus on the second textbox. Instead, it executes the rest of the `onchange` function and then it scrolls the page. By the time the page has scrolled, the event handler for the `scroll` event has already been setup.

Here's why: when an event happens in JavaScript, it is placed on a message queue (an internal component of the JavaScript run-time engine). Messages are removed from that queue and processed with each "turn" of the event loop. The amount of time between turns of the event loop vary, but typically each turn takes no more than 4 ms.

To solve your problem, you can setup the binding in the next turn of the event loop (after the `scroll` event has fired). To do that, developers typically do something like:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    document.onscroll = function (e) {
        console.log("scroll");
    };
}, 0);
```

Even though I specified a delay of 0 ms, the `setTimeout` callback won't fire until the next turn of the event loop, so it really happens after about 4 ms. You are guaranteed that the binding won't be setup until after the `focus` event has been processed (the `focus` message is always added to the message queue before the `setTimeout` message is added to the message queue, and the messages in the queue are processed in order).

There was a proposal to introduce a `setImmediate` function to JavaScript for the purpose of allowing developers to execute code in the next turn of the event loop, but global adoption of the function seems unlikely. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setImmediate

The function would work similarly to the hack above:

```
setImmediate(function () {
    document.onscroll = function (e) {
        console.log("scroll");
    };
});
```

If you're interested, there are a few polyfills for `setImmediate` that are faster than the `setTimeout` hack and use the HTML 5 `postMessage` API. See: https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate

Here's a JSBin of the fixed code running alongside the broken code: http://jsbin.com/laculukaqidu/1/edit?js,console,output